Regexp_extract in Hive
I am trying to parse out the words within a string and trying to use regexp. I am open to using any functions or logic that will work.
Example: in one of the columns i have:
Variable1 =‘Y’ and variable3=5
Variable2 ne 2 and variable5 ne’A’
My output needs to capture all the variable word names before the delimiter =, ne
the variable names have a _ in it.
Appreciate any help. Thanks
Trying to use Regexp but no luck yet

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
